# Eclipse shortcut to find all children class that override a method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there an Eclipse shortcut to see all class overriding the method `m`?
[image: Overriding methods]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Highlight/select/put-cursor-on the method name and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Obviously limited to the classes defined on the classpath ("build path" in Eclipse terminology)

Answer (score 7):

CTRL + T – Show inheritance tree of the class.

F4 – Show type hierarchy of on a class.

And please refer the following URLs for other eclipse shortcuts.

http://javapapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Eclipse-Shortcuts.pdf
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you double click on a method name to highlight it, and then do F4, then the selected method appears higlighted in the class hierarchy window, although Eclipse 2019.09 does not actually jump to it.