# Eclipse: What is a better way to find the implementation of a virtual function?

Tags: eclipse, virtual-functions

Eclipse: What is a better way to find the implementation of a virtual function?

I am now using "Search" to look at every places that have the virtual function name. Apparently it is a very  ineffective way.

[Update 1]: Specifically I am reading the code of the liveMedia of live555. I import it as C++ code in Eclipse.

Comment: What is a  virtual function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean abstract functions.

Right-click on the function and select 'Declarations'.

Comment: Thanks. Right click -> Declarations -> Workspace. It works. But if I use:  Right click -> Declarations -> Project. It does not work (0 matches). Why should I not select "Project"?

Answer (score 0):

select function or method and press F3 you will reach at method creation.....

Answer (score 0):

You can see this on the Type hierarchy which can be opened by:

- double click on method name
- Ctrl + T

or by right clicking on the method name and navigating in the menu.

This opens a class tree showing only classes that implement the method, and if you click on a class it jumps to the implementation for that class.

You have to be in the .hpp file annoyingly to open the Type hierarchy, if you are on the .cpp you have to first jump to the .hpp with Ctrl + Click on the method name.

Related question: [Eclipse shortcut to find all children class that override a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078749/eclipse-shortcut-to-find-all-children-class-that-override-a-method)

Tested in Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0) with [this test project](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ide-test-projects/blob/fe6a102d6147c72d6de061e95f0be5a07ab10fc4/cpp/animal.hpp#L8).